# Javascript Array values appearing twice

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am hoping someone can help me. I have 5 input boxes and I am getting the values from these boxes and placing them into an Array in JavaScript and then sorting these values alphabetically this works perfectly. The issue is that for some reason when the values are put into the array it doubles them and it gives the values twice. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<form>
   *Choice A
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="cha" class="answer" rows="1" cols="10">

    *Choice B
    <input type="text"  maxlength="100" name="chb" class="answer" rows="1" cols="10">

    *Choice C
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="chc" class="answer" rows="1" cols="10" >

    *Choice D
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="chd" class="answer" rows="1" cols="10" >

    *Choice E
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="che" class="answer" rows="1" cols="10" >

    <input type = "button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()" value ="Selection Sort in Ascending Order">
    <br/>
    <div id="showInputValues">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var getBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    getBtn.onclick = function() {
        getTheData() ;
    }

    function getTheData() {
        var answer = document.getElementsByClassName("answer");
        var inputValues = new Array();

        for (var i in answer) {
            //extract the value of input elements
            var singleVal = answer[i].value;
            if (singleVal !== "" && singleVal !== undefined) {
                inputValues.push(singleVal);
            } 
        }
        console.log(inputValues);
        inputValues.sort();
        //Display sorted values on form
        console.log(inputValues);
        alert( inputValues);
        // set the sorted values :
        for (var i=0;i<inputValues.length;i++) {
            //extract the value of input elements
            console.log(i);
            console.log(inputValues[i]);
            answer[i].value = inputValues[i];
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code in a consistent manner. When code isn't formatted correctly, it is more difficult to understand, debug, and check for syntax errors. People will also respond much more favorably to your question if it's formatted well. Tools like [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) can help you format your code correctly.

Comment: The expected behavior is that the user will enter 5 choices in input fields and then once the button is clicked these values will be placed into an array and sorted alphabetically and then the new sorted values will appear in the input fields. For example if I enter Apple, Bananna, Orange, Pear, Zebra. The values after sorting will be Apple, Apple, Bananna, Bananna, Orange,Orange, Pear, Pear, Zebra, Zebra.

Comment: Im not asking anyone to write code for me. Im simply asking can someone explain why the values are doubling. Thanks for being rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, not an actual array. If you `console.dir(answer)` you'll see that, in addition to the numeric keys you would find in an array, the object has one key per named element. [for in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop over every property on an object, so you're getting your values twice.

Comment: This is a better explanation for what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Good to know this about the for in loops, this info will definitely be helpful for the future. I appreciate it.

Comment: Stumbled upon this looking for how I am getting same keys in React... Anyway, like this answer says, you're looking at an HTMLCollection "array-like" object. You can: Array.from(HTML Collection) to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this loop:

```
for (var i in answer) {
    //extract the value of input elements
    var singleVal = answer[i].value;
    if (singleVal !== "" && singleVal !== undefined) {
        inputValues.push(singleVal);
    }
}
```

I could be a bit off on this explanation, but the `answer` variable comes from a `document.getElementsByClassName(...)` which returns a NodeList. The NodeList includes the elements twice, once with indexes and once with the name attribute. That is why your loop will find two of each element in the collection.

It will work if you change it to a traditional for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: To elaborate slightly, the nodes repeat, first with index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, then again with cha, chb, chc, chd, che.  By switching to the integer index as described above you will only hit the first 5.

Comment: Thanks that actually makes things a lot clearer.  Changing back to a traditional for-loop has fixed the issue. Thanks for an excellent explanation!!